# .htaccess rewrite seems to fail on longer strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule files/name/(.*).(pdf)$/ download.php?file=$1.$2&tkn=token
RewriteRule files/name/(.*).(pdf)$ download.php?file=$1.$2&tkn=token
RewriteRule files/name2/(.*).(pdf)$/ download2.php?file=$1.$2&tkn=token
RewriteRule files/name2/(.*).(pdf)$ download2.php?file=$1.$2&tkn=token
```

The folders name and name2 contain identical files.  download.php and download2.php are identical.

The files/name/(.*) rewrite rule will redirect nearly all files to download.php, but fails on, what seems to be long file names. Two files I know it has failed on are:

abcdefghijklmn-abcdefghij.pdf

Pbcdefg ab abc Abdefghij 2.PDF

The files/name2/(.*) rule catches all files, including the two that are failing in the first rule.  Literally, if I go to http://www.domain.com/files/names/abcdefghijklmn-abcdefghij.pdf, the server will serve me the file directly.  If I go to http://www.domain.com/files/names2/abcdefghijklmn-abcdefghij.pdf, (just add 2 to names), the server will redirect me to http://www.domain.com/download2.php?file=abcdefghijklmn-abcdefghij.pdf&tkn=token

I've been trying to get this to work for hours, and I have no idea why the first rule won't work.  Is there some weird idiosyncrasy I'm missing?

Comment: I'm assuming these are going to be pdf files?

Comment: Yes, these are PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule files/name2/(.*)\.pdf$ /download2.php?file=$1.pdf&tkn=token [R,L]
RewriteRule files/name/(.*)\.pdf$ /download.php?file=$1.pdf&tkn=token [R,L]
```

Comment: Tried this and it redirects to:

http://www.domain.com/home/user/public_html/download.php?file=testfile.pdf&tkn=token

It added the root path for some reason?

Comment: Do you have Godaddy by chance? Anyway, Try adding a slash in front download.php and download2.php like the update.